# Opinion on building a computer for work purposes?

Tags: memory, cpu, computer-building

I need some opinions :) First post on superuser.

Work purposes meaning video and photoshop editing. I'm a programmer and coding software doesn't require any power at all really...

I'm currently using a mid 2010 macbook pro 17 inch and have been using a mac since 2008. Always thought they're nice and after the new release of the latest macbooks it made me realize I won't have a good portable replacement for at least 4 more years. So.. I'm thinking of offloading the heavy duty stuff onto a desktop.

I'm looking at spending 1-1.5k on a computer/parts. In the long run (5 years?) does it seem reasonable for me to buy a tower and toss parts at it? That way when a newer CPU comes around, I can swap out the cpu's? (e.g. i9 processor if/when it comes out). So my cost of upgrading would be a CPU and not an entire computer?

The more I think about it, the only thing that would ever change is the mother board and CPU, then I could simply plug in all the other things, like ram and hook up the fans to it again right? What's 400-500 vs a whole nother 1.5k to have "the best", AND I'd have the latest USB, thunderbolt etc plugs that are the current speeds right? (stuck with usb 2.0 on mac lol). AND I'd get the added benefit of being able to swap out graphic cards if I ever (never) want to play a game or something like that.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Comment: If you have not build any desktop PC before, especially being a spoiled Apple user, I would advise against it. You will spend more money than 1.5k and likely will end up with unreliable piece of DIY "engineering".

Comment: Ali, then start small? Gotta build one eventually right? I do a lot of wiring and technical stuff as a hobby, just never touched a computer's internals aside from fans, ram, renew the arctic silver paste and replace hard drive.

Comment: Damn I'm confused as I saw my own name as the one asking question.... but if you don't want to deal with all the parts changing, you may want to consider some small form factor PC like the Intel NUC (most parts are built into the box, and you only need to add RAM and SSD as needed)

Comment: Haha, Darius, I just felt the same thing thinking how am I giving advice to myself!? Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite ambiguous and subjective, but I will answer with a few facts that might help your decision.

1. A tower will get you much more bang for your buck performance wise than a laptop no matter what companies you go with because they don't have to optimize for battery life, space, weight, power consumption and more.
2. Yes you can upgrade a PC as it gets older. Changing out the motherboard and CPU is less of a likely scenario, but upgrading memory, hard drives/SSD's and GPU are quite common and cost a lot less than changing the whole thing. Changing out the motheroard and CPU can sometimes make you change your power supply, RAM, GPU or others depending on what new technology is on the new stuff you buy.

Either way, it depends, if you want more raw power and upgrade possibilities, go for the tower. If you want portability, go for the laptop.